# How to move files already uploaded to a new subfolder?

Tags: files

I've got a bunch of files in sites/default/files that I'd like to move to a sites/default/files/subfolder to avoid a big mess.

The fields uploading files have been configured to put them in the right folders in the future. What I'm looking for is a solution to organising files already uploaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Relevant Similar Module Review page: [File Uploading and Managing](https://groups.drupal.org/node/20291) (section "Automatic Filesystem Structuring")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module [**File (Field) Paths**](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) allows this per file field.

For Drupal 8:

1. <kbd>Manage fields</kbd>: <kbd>Edit</kbd> the File field
2. Check the option "Enable File (Field) Paths?"
3. Expand "File (Field) Path settings"
4. Check the option "**Retroactive update**"
5. <kbd>Save settings</kbd>

Now all of this field’s files will be moved/renamed (you should see a progress bar). This is a one-time action, so if you need to move the files again, you have to repeat these steps.

If you always want to move the files when the path changes, you can check the "**Active updating**" option.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for [File Maintenance](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_maintenance).

> Ever wanted to move files from your sites/default/files directory (or
>   whatever you have configured) to a (new) subdirectory? Never did it
>   because you knew it's a damn mess since you need do move the physical
>   file, adjust the database files table and look through all the
>   node_revisions table and other content to adjust the link to the file
>   so as not to break your site?

That should cover any files that are managed under the files table (pretty much any field you should have). If you have any other files under sites/default/files ***that aren't managed by Drupal***, then custom redirect htaccess rules should cover those files.

Comment: wow, how could I not google that:)?! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just note that File Maintenance module for Drupal 7 is still work in 
progress, and no file operations can be performed yet, but the file browser UI is functional and informative. So its usefulness is partial right now: mostly to find out which files are in the filesystem and not in database, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution to be the [Organize Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/organize_files) module

Answer (score 0):

1. In `files` table change the `uri` column value from sites/default/files to sites/default/files subfolder.
2. Now move all the files from sites/default/files to sites/default/files subfolder.